# Which internet connection speed is ideal for 30-40 PC with DSL connection on a cafe?

Tags: internet, dsl

Well, i am subscribed to local ISP for 8 Mbps downstream for two computers at home managed by WAG120N broadband modem.  it may not be enough when simultaneously watching a video at both computers. On the other hand, i imagine what internet connection speed is adequate for a cyber cafe consisting of 30-40 client computers considering this fact ?

Edit : lets say, we don't want any interruption/drops and many PC's are used to play online games, watching videos at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 1-2 Mbps per PC should be more than enough.
This will suffice for HD video streaming as well as playing MMORPGs.

But assuming not all the PCs would be doing heavy usage at the same time, cosider allotting 512 Kbps to each PC.
But again that will depend on kind of customers you expect. If all the PCs are to be used for online gaming at same time, then 512Kbps per PC would not suffice.

In case of reliability, that will depend on service providers which will specific to your country.

Comment: what does 1-2 Mbps per client exactly mean? for 30-40 client , i should have 1-2 multiply 30-40 client ?

Comment: MMORPGs rather need low latency not high bandwidth